# Jointly (absolutely) continuous random variables $X_1, X_2$ are independent if and only if their joint p.d.f. is the product of marginal p.d.f.'s

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, independence

All random variables are defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. I'm trying to prove a statement at page 17 from [this](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf) lecture note. Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

All random variables are defined on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

> **Proposition 3.4.** $X_1, X_2$ are independent (denoted by $X_1 \perp X_2$) if and only if
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \in B_1, X_2 \in B_2\right\}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \in B_1\right\}\right) \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_2 \in B_2\right\}\right), \quad \forall B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
> $$

Assume now $X_1, X_2$ are *jointly continuous* random variables, that is, there exists a Borel-measurable function $p_{X_1, X_2}: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ (=joint pdf) such that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{\left(X_1, X_2\right) \in B\right\}\right)=\int_B p_{X_1, X_2}\left(x_1, x_2\right) d x_1 d x_2, \quad \forall B \in \mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)
$$

**Then** $X_1, X_2$ are independent if and only if the function $p_{X_1, X_2}$ can be factorized as follows:
$$
p_{X_1, X_2}\left(x_1, x_2\right)=p_{X_1}\left(x_1\right) p_{X_2}\left(x_2\right), \quad \forall\left(x_1, x_2\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2.
$$

---

**Proof:** By **Prop 3.4.** and Fubini's theorem, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&X_1 \perp X_2\\
\iff \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \in B_1, X_2 \in B_2\right\}\right)&=\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_1 \in B_1\right\}\right) \mathbb{P}\left(\left\{X_2 \in B_2\right\}\right) \\
\int_{B_1 \times B_2} p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2) &= \left [ \int_{B_1 \times \Omega} p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2) \right ] \cdot \left [ \int_{\Omega \times B_2} p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2) \right ] \\
\iff \int_{B_1 \times B_2} p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2) &= \left [ \int_{B_1} \underbrace{\int_\Omega p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d x_2}_{=: p_{X_1} (x_1)} \mathrm d x_1 \right ] \cdot \left [ \int_{B_2} \underbrace{\int_\Omega p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d x_1}_{=: p_{X_2} (x_2)} \mathrm d x_2 \right ] \\
\iff \int_{B_1 \times B_2} p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2) &= \left [ \int_{B_1} p_{X_1} (x_1) \mathrm d x_1 \right ] \cdot \left [ \int_{B_2} p_{X_2} (x_2) \mathrm d x_2 \right ] \\
\iff \int_{B_1 \times B_2} p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2) &= \int_{B_1} \int_{B_2} p_{X_1} (x_1) p_{X_2} (x_2) \mathrm d x_1  \mathrm d x_2 \\
\iff \int_{B_1 \times B_2} p_{X_1, X_2} (x_1, x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2) &= \int_{B_1 \times B_2} p_{X_1} (x_1) p_{X_2} (x_2) \mathrm d (x_1, x_2). 
\end{align}
$$

Notice that the last equality is equivalent to
$$
p_{X_1, X_2} = p_{X_1} p_{X_2} \quad \text{almost everywhere}.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first step in the equation of integrals? I.e. changing the integration domain from $B_1\times B_2$ to $B_1\times \Omega$ and $\Omega\times B_2$. I guess $\Omega$ should be $\mathbb{R}$ in this case right?

Comment: @courageousmartingale you are right! I made a mistake. I should be $\mathbb R$, not $\Omega$.

Comment: And is this operation of transforming one integral into the product of two integrals a general result?

Comment: @courageousmartingale could you mention the transformation you refered  in the previous comment?

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I misread the chain of implications. The first equation of integrals is equivalent to the equation of probabilities above it so it makes sense. Then I would say this proof is perfectly fine :)